# How to change MS query data source in excel with vba?

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I have a couple tables that are connected to an access database through Microsoft Query. If I move the location of the access file or I need a way to update the source location especially since I will need to share this file with other people.

All the connections are ODBC and are from the same access file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the connection are uniform I looped through each one and replaced the current source file with the file selected through the windows file explorer.

```
Sub SwitchODBCSource()
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
Dim sOldConnection As String, sNewConnection As String


getfilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
FileType = ".accdb"
    If InStr(getfilePath, FileType) Then
        fileName = Dir(getfilePath)
        filePath = Replace(getfilePath, "\" & fileName, "")



        For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
            With conn
                 conn.ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False

                conn.ODBCConnection.CommandType = xlCmdSql
                conn.ODBCConnection.Connection = Array(Array( _
                "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & filePath & "\" & fileName & ";DefaultDir=" _
                ), Array( _
               filePath & ";DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;" _
                ))

              End With
        Next conn
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        Call Sheet1.dropDown
        Set conn = Nothing
    Else
    MsgBox ("Can only use " & FileType & " files")
    End If
End Sub
```